# SSIS How to drop a table assigned to a variable + a suffix

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to drop a table assigned to a variable name `@Table_Name` and the corresponding `_staging` table along with it during a task on the package.

Example;

- [dbo].[Customers]
- [dbo].[Customers_Staging]

I already have a task that drops the table but I need to create another task that drops the table + _staging suffix.

How do I write this within the Execute SQL Task query?

I have got these 2 versions;

- `DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = 'DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@Table_Name + '_staging'); EXEC(@sql);`
- `DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = 'DROP TABLE ' + @Table_Name + '_Staging;'; EXEC sp_executesql @sql;`

Both return the error "Must declare the scalar variable "@sql"

Comment: Neither of those statements are valid; the object must be a literal. Build the *SQL statement* you want to run in SSIS and then pass that to the Execute T-SQL Task. Otherwise you'll need to pass the table name as a parameter and then use dynamic SQL within your Execute T-SQL Task.

Comment: `DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = 'DROP TABLE ' + @Table_Name + '_Staging;'; EXEC sp_executesql @sql;`

Comment: @Charlieface, if I run this I get the error `"Must declare the scalar variable "@sql"`. The parameter mapping for `@Table_Name` is set correctly with the type being nvarchar

Comment: There is no way you ran that code, it starts `DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)` so it is declared. Unless you ran both statements as separate batches?

Answer (score 0):

The suggested duplicate question is valid for SQL but the nuance of SSIS makes this a different question, IMAO.

The crux of the issue is how do I mix native SSIS variables with the existing Tasks.

An Execute SQL Task gives you 3 options for source types: Direct input (default), File connection, Variable. It's the latter we want.

Create another variable of type string. I'll assume it's called @[User::DropTable].

The magic, as it were, is to use an `Expression` on the variable which is built on an existing variable. Here we're just doing boring string concatenation.

```
"DROP TABLE " + @[User::Table_Name] + ";" + "DROP TABLE " + @[User::Table_Name] + "_staging" + ";"
```

Where things are going to get a bit more dicey is whether the supplied values of "[dbo].[Customers]" is the actual value in the table name as building the _staging variant is going to result in an incorrect table name of "[dbo].[Customers]_staging"

The other good thing about this approach is you can put a breakpoint on the Execute SQL Task and inspect/copy the drop command value to ensure you've done the string concatenation correctly.

And if you don't want that approach and want parameters, then you can leave the SQL Source Type as Direct Input and in the Parameter Mapping section, map VariableName @[User::TableName] to Parameter name "0" (assuming OLE DB Connection Manager)

```
DECLARE @tn nvarchar(max) = ?
, @sql nvarchar(max) = NULL;

SET @sql = 'DROP TABLE ' + @tn; 
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

SET @sql = 'DROP TABLE ' + @tn+ '_Staging;'; 
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

That allows us to map the SSIS Variable @[User::Table_Name] to a SQL variable I named @tn and then do string concatenation within the query.